# How to create a dynamic array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create the following array dynamically, for example:

```
var data = { point: [
              { x:5, y:8 },
              { x:8, y:10},
              ]};

 console.log(data.point[0].x);   // 5  n=0
 console.log(data.point[1].y);   // 10 n=1
```

At some point my application needs to expand the array to more than 2 items (n=0, n=1). Please let me know how to do that (i.e. n = 9 ).

Comment: Just assign it. If you just want to insert at the back, use `push()`. If you want to insert at front, use `unshift()`.

Comment: use loop to iterate on the conditions you want to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = {'points' : []};

function addPoint(x, y) {
    data.points.push({'x' : x, 'y' : y});
}

function getPoint(index) {
    return data.points[index];
}

addPoint(10, 20);
addPoint(5, 3);

var p = getPoint(1);
alert(p.x + ", " + p.y); //alerts => "5, 3"
```

This would work for any arbitrary number of points.

**Update**

To clear the array

```
function clearPoints() {
    data.points = [];
}
```

**Update 2**

These little functions will work okay if you have a simple page. If this points handling is going to end up being part of a larger system, it may be better to do something like this:

```
var data = {
    'points' : [], 
    addPoint : function(x, y) {
        this.points.push({
            'x' : x, 
            'y' : y
        });
    }, 
    getPoint : function(index) {
        return this.points[index];
    }, 
    clearPoints : function() {
        this.points = [];
    }, 
    removePoint : function(index) {
        this.points.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
alert(data.points.length); // => 0

data.addPoint(1, 2);
data.addPoint(8, 12);
data.addPoint(3, 7);
alert(data.points.length); // => 3

var p = data.getPoint(2); //p = {x:3, y:7};

data.removePoint(1); 
alert(data.points.length); // => 2

data.clearPoints();
alert(data.points.length); // => 0
```

It may allow you to keep your point handling a little cleaner and easier to use and update.

Comment: Thanks jwatts1980, interesting....after calling addPoint(x,y) for number of times. For example, 5 times.  At some point, I would like to reset (clear) the array and start from the beginning (i.e the array 'data' has no element in it).  How could I do that?

Comment: Excellent...Thank you.  I will try it and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: Update 2 got syntax error at addPoint, I put missing ')', but still not working....

Comment: Whoops. My fault. I put equal signs instead of colons. Corrected. Tested. Works.

Comment: Thanks..what about "this.points.push({..." does not have closing ")"?

Comment: Wow. I'm going to have to work on being a little more thorough! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add element to an array.

```
var point = {x:1,y:1};
data.point.push(point);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use method 'push' like this code

```
        var data = { point: [
                      { x:5, y:8 },
                      { x:8, y:10},
                      ]};

         console.log(data.point[0].x);   // 5  n=0
         console.log(data.point[1].y);   // 10 n=1

        data.point.push({x:4,y:3});

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.point));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function as stated, or add additional items to the array using an index, which is preferred in the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).  The latter method does require that you have a pointer to the last index.

> Note that since assigning values to an array is faster than using
>   push() you should use assignment where possible.

```
for(var i=lastIndex; i < numOfNewPoints; i++){
    data.point[i] = {x:4, y:3};
}
```